# How do you deploy a .war?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am learning how to write .jsp projects. In eclipse my project runs on localhost just fine. I exported a .war file and went to the tomcat manager of my remote server and used the "select .war to deploy app" button. When I browse to the app the server says "HTTP Status 404 - /HelloJsp". If I try to browse to the .jsp pages I get the same thing. On the server I can see that the project was unpacked in the webapps folder in tomcat under the project name. I've rebooted the server, stopped and started tomcat but I still get the same error. The server manager says the project is running. In the .war I can see that eclipse created a META-INF folder with MANAFEST.MF inside. Another folder called WEB-INF with folders classes and lib and web.xml file. Them my two .jsp pages at the root of the .war. From what I've read, it should run. Am I missing something?

contents of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloJsp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>HelloWorld.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you add the content of web.xml?

Comment: What's the context path of the application?

Comment: where would I find it?

Comment: Which jsp file you have in your application? index,default or hello world.jso

Comment: I have HelloWorld.jsp

Comment: You should have specified the context when you deployed it with the manager app.

Comment: Ok, I saw that online too. I've deployed it blank and with /HellJsp

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Check file **CATALINA_HOME\conf\tomcat-users.xml** like that: ( for example, administration user is "***admin***", and password also "***admin***")

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin, manager,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Step 2:**
Start Tomcat, run: **CATALINA_HOME\bin\startup.bat** (on Windows)

**Step 3:**
Go to: `http://localhost:8080`
[image]

**Step 4:** Press **Manager App** button

**Step 5:** In page `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` , in **Deploy** section --> **WAR file to deploy**, Press **Choose File** button, choose your war file, and press **Deploy** button.
[image]

Your application files will go to **CATALINA_HOME\webapps\WebAppName** . (**CATALINA_HOME** is your Tomcat installion directory)

**Step 6:** Go to `http://localhost:8080/WebAppName`

(in your case, launch your application by go to: `http://localhost:8080/HelloJsp` )

If you deploy your web application in real server, replace **localhost** by your **domain**.

Comment: thanks for the tutorial, I've much followed the same except for Linux. Not sure how, but it started working on it's own....